# Can I run/emulate my Vuejs project on my phone or use some kind of virtual device to emulate it from my Pc?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, debugging, mobile

Is it possible to emulate/run my Vue.js app on my own device => android (I already got the debugging mode active in the developers Section from Settings). I'm working on a big project and got assigned this issue => mobile version keyboard overlapping an input when focus state is active.
But the problem is that I can't/ don't know how to re-create the situation because I can't display that kind of keyboard on screen.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You could setup an Android emulator on your machine. Or use BrowserStack or SauceLabs to remotely start an Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert your vuejs builds into android applications with voltbuilder. Its super easy..
https://volt.build/docs/set_up/